# Sending a Delete request via laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I want to add a link for deleting in record list,but there is no example for how to create DELETE request in the documentation.

Below is my solution, but so ugly:

```
<td>
<form action="{{url('/crud/del/'. $post['id_currency'])}}" method="post">
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{--<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">--}}
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
{{--<a href="" class="btn btn-danger flaticon-layers"></a>--}}
</td>
```

After click delete i got message:

> "The page has expired due to inactivity.
>
> Please refresh and try again."

My controller:

```
 public function destroy($id)
 {
    $uri = env("API_URI");
    $headers = array(
        'Accept' => '*/*',
        'X-Access-Token' => '7e5ae27692ff7af65f9f26435d3f6496',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    );
    \Unirest\Request::delete($uri.'/currency/'.$id, $headers);
    return $this->index();
}
```

And route:

```
Route::delete('/crud/del/{id}',array('uses' => 'ApiController@destroy', 'as' => '/crud/del'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('tbl_name')->where('id','=',$id)->delete();
```

Comment: Could I suggest giving some extra information about your answer, rather than just a code one-liner?